# RSVP option not visible

Tags: android, android-calendar

I develop an Android app which syncs events from a backend into a calendar on my Android device.

But when I open the entries in the Calendar app the RSVP option is not visible :-(
When I invite someone to this event the option becomes visible.

Is it possible to create a Calendar entry with the [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) where the user can change it's rsvp state without inviting another person?

Currently when I add a new calendar entry I also add an entry to the Attendees table but I doesn't help :-(

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the case of how can an event creator not attend?

Comment: Yes, this `Going?` question does not appear if your create an entry for yourself. You have to invite someone else to see this